# Does Symfony 2 support Cassandra DB?

Tags: symfony, cassandra, nosql

I wanted to know if I can use Symphony 2 and Cassandra Database for a web project. 
I know that Symphony 2 supports NoSQL databases like MongoDB, but I am not sure if it do the same with Cassandra.

Any clarification would be welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Natively - no, but you could use PHP client for Cassandra, for example https://github.com/thobbs/phpcassa or even Symfony2 Bundle which just wrap up the phpcassa - https://github.com/amigos-del-rigor/ADRCassandraBundle.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. I found in the link of phpcassa that you mentionned that phpcassa is deprecated and they suggest this PHP driver : https://github.com/datastax/php-driver. But php-driver is still in version alpha: Can we use it for an entreprise project?

Comment: I definitely not sure, sorry! Check out a list of the [PHP-based tools](http://planetcassandra.org/client-drivers-tools/#PHP). I guess it'll be not so hard to create a wrapper bundle for one of them.

Comment: Also, it looks like datastax PHP driver is progressing really fast, so PROBABLY it will be released quite soon: "Excluding merges, 5 authors have pushed 122 commits to master and 136 commits to all branches. On master, 134 files have changed and there have been 2,237 additions and 3,534 deletions." (March 19, 2015 – April 19, 2015)

Answer (score 0):

You can this bundle https://github.com/M6Web/CassandraBundle build on top of the official driver from datastax

works fine whith php 5.6 or php7